# Program crashed using libxml2 in ubuntu 17

Tags: linux, ubuntu, libxml2

I am porting my working code from ubuntu 14.x to 17.x.
I am getting error in function XMLMakeRootNode in Ubuntu 17.x
This code works fine in ubuntu 14.x version.

**[SIGSEGV]**

Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff785937b in xmlDocSetRootElement () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2

**[Crash Dump]:**

/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x37140)[0x7f72215ac140]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2(xmlDocSetRootElement+0x3b)[0x7f7222daa37b]

P.S.

While compiling program I am getting some warning as below:
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XmlGetRootNode’; did you mean ‘xmlRootNode’? [-Wimplicit-function-declare]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following on Ubuntu 17.x to make sure that you have all the latest libraries for libxml2?

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2

sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev

sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev

sudo apt-get install xml-core
```